# Fixing gcc undefined include<> by manually installing library

Tags: c++, go, gcc, tesseract

I am running the golang command "go get -t github.com/otiai10/gosseract" , causing the error `tessbridge.cpp:5:10: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory, #include <leptonica/allheaders.h>`. That library is https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica. How do I install it from source so that the gcc command will work.

Before that command was producing the error "gcc not found", but then I followed https://superuser.com/questions/1294343/install-gcc-in-git-for-windows-bash-environment to setup gcc on windows.

I have not been able to find any references for what gcc expects when it encounters an include<>, and where those files should be located on the file system for it to link properly. Is it possible to install this library manually?

Comment: leptonica has detailed instructions on how to build and install it.  Read the README.html file.

Comment: Have you looked at the [readme](http://www.leptonica.org/source/README.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is much simpler solution for you. There was no need to install `gcc` on `git-bash`.

1. Install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/). Follow complete installation guide.
2. On MSYS2 console enter the following commands :

```sh
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-leptonica
```

3. Add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to `PATH`.

---

First step can be further simplified if you use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Just run these commands in elevated powershell : (Ignore first command if `choco` is already installed.)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Reopen elevated powershell and run these:

```
choco install -y msys2 --params="/InstallDir:C:\msys64"
refreshenv
$env:Path += ";C:\msys64\usr\bin"
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-leptonica
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;" + $env:Path, "User")
```

Comment: thanks your steps helped with the error. Although im still curious about my question in principle. Can i replicate what ever those pacman command did manually? Maybe if not specifically could you high level explain where the files for include<> are store that allow them to be accessed by gcc

Comment: @lufthansa747 The headers are installed in `C:\msys64\mingw64\include`. Those `pacman` (package manager) commands are a part of the MSYS project. Yeah you sure can do what it did. It basically installed `gcc` and `leptonica`. That is _nearly_ equivalent to building these two projects from their source itself and moving the built headers and library files into proper folders.